# TFS hosted build controller to send email alerts

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

Has anyone ever configured the: tfs.visualstudio.com "hosted build controller" to send emails when a build is started, failed, or completed?
Note: this is not TFS - Team Foundation Server, it's the Team Foundation Services hosted by MS.

I'd like to be able to send an alert so my testers know to take a break during the builds.

Answer (score 6):

You can setup team alerts using the Team Foundation Service.  It is also available in Team Foundation Server for on-premises as well.  I have a walkthrough available here:  http://www.edsquared.com/2012/02/09/Creating+EMail+Alerts+For+Team+Members+In+TFS.aspx

[image: Build Team Alerts in Team Foundation Service]

Comment: I have an alert set up identical to the one in your image, but the 'Requested For' [me] filter is being ignored and everyone in the team is notified. Shouldn't this filter only send an email to the person who triggered the build or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @philreed That's really odd.  Are you using Visual Studio Online or Team Foundation Server?  We'll likely need to look into it.  You can create a free support ticket here to get that ball rolling:  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/cloud-services-assisted-support-vs

Comment: This is on VSO. The alert has been in the system for a while but it only started sending emails to everyone this week. Previously it only sent to the individual who triggered the CI build.

Comment: @philreed Yeah, definitely let the support team know so they can start investigating the details.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set alerts in the project portal. Just click on the small cog on the upper right corner and click on the Alerts tab.

There you can customize alerts for your project.

By the way, you can do that inside Visual Studio as well, in the Team menu.

Comment: This worked most recently for me when using Visual Studio Online to set up Build Alerts for my project.

Answer (score 1):

I use Team Foundation Server and its very easy to create alerts there. This is what I found for the team foudnation service
:
http://blog.nwcadence.com/team-alerts-in-visual-studio-11-team-foundation-service/